# How to set webcam parameters programatically on Microsoft Lifecam Cinema (e.g. switch off autofocus)

Tags: windows, webcam

The Microsoft Lifecam Cinema software has several options to control focusing, exposure and so on.  I need to control these programatically for a machine vision project.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: try to use microsoft lifecam driver for set setting in your lifecam i think that is work for u ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB toolbox for image acquisition allow access to the full functionality of the LifeCam. E.g. focus. However the provided driver has a problem, which Microsoft refuses to deal professional with - they claim that it is MATLAB that has a problem. So at the moment I cannot control brightness and exposure, two parameters that should be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem on a photo booth kiosk I built. To get around it, I created a simple command line utility to set these preferences and allow for reapplying them at startup.

You can find more details on downloading and using it in this Microsoft Answers question:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/is-it-possible-to-save-auto-focus-auto-color/e6b812e3-5e52-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5